# virtual functions...why is this private?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I'm trying to make the following bit of code to work...

```
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class container{
public:
    virtual T func_x(){
        T temp;
        //do stuff with list<t> test
        return temp;
    }
private:
    std::list<T> test;
};

template <typename T>
class container2 : public container<T>{
public:
    virtual T func_x(){
        T temp;
        //do different stuff with list<T> test
        return temp;
    }
};
```

What I want to be able to do is declare

```
container<T> x;
container2<T> y;
```

And be able to have y have access to all the public functions of x, except that it behaves differently for func_x.

The problem I have now is that func_x in class container2 cannot use;

```
std::list<T> test;
```

I have even tried making class container completely public. Still no dice. Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to match your follow-up question. Also, in the future, don't change the original question, but rather ask a new one. It can get misleading for others who read the question and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members are by default `private` for classes:

```
template <typename T>
class container2 : public container<T>{
    //************
    // no modifier
    virtual T func_x(){
        T temp;
        //do different stuff with list<T> test
        return temp;
    }
private:
    std::list<T> test;
};
```

means that `func_x` is `private`, since no modifier is specified.

You need to explicitly declare `func_x` as public, as you have for `class container`.

"Just because it's `public` in the base class doesn't mean it's automatically that way for the derived".

EDIT:

If you want base class members to be accessible in derived classes, you must declare them either `protected` or `public`. So, to answer your follow-up question, change

```
private:
    std::list<T> test;
```

to

```
protected:
    std::list<T> test;
```

Also, in the future, don't edit the question to ask a new one. You should create a new question to deal with the new issue. It can be misleading for others who see answers that no longer apply to the new question.

Comment: I would add: just because it's `public` in the base doesn't mean it's automatically that way for the derived

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `public:` to your class declaration: otherwise, all members declared are private by default.

```
template <typename T>
class container2 : public container<T>{
public: // <<==== ADD THIS
    virtual T func_x(){
        T temp;
        //do different stuff with list<T> test
        return temp;
    }
private:
    std::list<T> test;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `func_x` is hidden by your derived object, because you've redefined it, as `private` in derived.

You need to make it public.